# Will my potatoes grow?

Tags: potatoes

Could not think of a better title. I got a small bag of blue potatoes (forgot the variety) for planting and I brought them home at 7:00 PM. But I forgot to take them out of the truck until about 6:00 PM the next day. It got around 75°F (24°C) the other day so should I be worried that the potatoes will not grow? When I cut them they will still "juicy", and the eyes were not falling off. Kinda worried they won't grow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are somewhat in need of relaxing.

The blue potatoes that keep coming up in my garden (despite being harvested, some always seem to escape and grow the next year, for at least 3 years in a row now) were found, rather sad, dried up and moldy (with long, but rather shriveled, sprouts) under a bag of chicken feed, in mid-summer - evidently the person who bought them (in the spring) put the "excess" under the chicken feed and they did not come to light until the chicken feed was empty. Given the opportunity, they (or most of them) grew happily. I did give them a soak in a bucket of water before planting.

23 hours with a brief stint at 75F is nothing to worry about, in my experience.